# Imposing condition of specification of product of $n$ of imaginary numbers on coefficients of imaginary numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

I asked the same question but with some fatal mistake that makes the question unanswerable - so I decided to delete it and start new.

Connecting from [The set of numbers that when multiplied do not get decomposed into $sx+ty$ while the numbers themselves are of form $ax+byi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287965/the-set-of-numbers-that-when-multiplied-do-not-get-decomposed-into-sxty-while) (it's however an independent question.):

> Suppose that there are $n$ numbers that are in the following format:
>   $a+bi$. Each number has different combination of $a$ and $b$. $a,b$
>   must be non-zero integers.
>
> Suppose that we impose the following rule: $a^2-b^2 = k_1x$ and $2ab = k_2y$.
>
> $k_1$ and $k_2$ are free non-zero integers - by free, I mean that they
>   can be different for different numbers. However, $x$ and $y$ are fixed
>   (set).

Let us say call the real part of each number as $a_i$ and the integer coefficient of imaginary part as $b_i$. Let us say that $a_i = r_{i_1}r_{i_2}d$ and $b_i = r_{i_3}r_{i_4}d$ where $d$ is greatest common divisor of all $a_i$s and $b_i$s. $r_{i_1} = p_{i_1}^{e_{i_1}}$ where $p_{i_1}$ is the prime factor that only one(each) number's $a_i$ has, and $e_{i_1}$ is the corresponding exponent to the prime factor. (for readability, I will write: pi1, ei1)

$r_{i_3} = p_{i_3}^{e_{i_3}}$ where $p_{i_3}$ is the prime factor that only one number's $b_i$ has, and $e_{i_3}$ is the corresponding exponent to the prime factor. (pi3,ei3)

$r_{i_2}, r_{i_4}$ can be any non-zero integer.

Let us say that $t_1 = \text{product of all $r_{i_1}$'s}$ and $t_2 = \text{product of all $r_{i_2}$'s}$.

We would like to impose condition on these numbers so that out of all possible multiplication products of $n$ numbers (that is, this set includes multiplication that has duplicate number), only when $n$ different numbers are multiplied the product can be written as the form: $k_3t_1 + k_4d + k_5t_2$ where $k_3,k_4,k_5$ can be any non-zero integer.

Is this possible?

Comment: So, you are assuming that for each $i$ there is a prime that divides $a_i$ and only $a_i$, and a prime that divides $b_i$ and only divides $b_i$? Also, $t_1$ and $t_2$ relate only to the $a_i$ and have nothing to do with the $b_i$? Also, with all this set-up, I'd expect a significant payoff; what good will it do you to have an answer to this problem? Where is it going?

Comment: yes, and I'm doing this because of economics dynamic issue. But I don't think this qualifies as needing economics tag.

Comment: I'll give my 150 reputation points for a person who solves the problem.

Comment: @user27515, there is a way to offer a bounty on a question. See the faq.

Comment: Siona, tag doesn't worry me, would just be nice to understand the motivation. Maybe one could get away with less?

Comment: "This question has not received enough attention." That's true, it hasn't received enough attention from the person posting it, who chooses not to give any idea as to why anyone would want to know the answer to such a contrived problem.

Comment: @GerryMyerson It is not contrived thing - this is so possible in economics - econometrics. I am just trying to model things - though a little differently. I am just imposing constraint. If you need of all of these explanations I will provide all those. I myself is currently working on it, though I suck at math - so with help of my friends.

Comment: So we have $n$ numbers in $\mathbb Z[i]$ such that their squares have real part divisible by $x$ and imaginary part divisible by $y$ - but $x,y$ are not used anywhere else in the problem description?? For some reason you conclude (or require?) that each $a_i, b_i$ has a prime factor that does not occur as factor of any of the other numbes? But what about $a_1=4, a_2=6, a_3=9$? Are they simply forbidden or did you miss something?