# $n$ fractional gaussian rational numbers and set of rules to govern them

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

Suppose that there are $n$ Gaussian rational numbers of form $a_t + b_ti$. For any $t$th number, $a_t$ and $b_t$ are both constrained to be non-zero rational numbers (fractions). Suppose that we impose the following: $a_t^2 - b_t^2 = c/d $ while $a_tb_t = e/f$ where $c,d,e,f$ are non-zero integers.

We also impose the following condition: For all possible $n$ products of imaginary numbers (the product may be the multiplying the product of the multiplication of same number with the product of some number combination), only when $n$ different numbers are multiplied, the resulting product cannot be converted into $(\frac{g}{h}+\frac{j}{k}i)(\frac{c}{d} + \frac{e}{f}i)$  where $g,h,j,k$ can be any integer.

Is this possible?

Comment: I must say this is a very obscure question. Is there any motivation behind it?

Comment: Pure math curiosity + modeling curiosity.

Comment: feeling cryptic I see....

Comment: It seems there are a few of these cryptic questions about multiplying Gaussians; http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287965/the-set-of-numbers-that-when-multiplied-do-not-get-decomposed-into-sxty-while and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290257/imposing-condition-of-specification-of-product-of-n-of-imaginary-numbers-on-co#comment632793_290257

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your $n$ product of imaginary numbers are from that initial set that you described, which I will call the 'Gaussian Rationals'.

The product of any such numbers will still lie in the Gaussian Rationals. In particular, we can set $c=d=f=1, e=0$.